# Are there no explicit Power modes in Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, power

Does Macbook Pro not provide power modes (Power Saver, High Performance, etc) like a Windows laptop?
If there is nothing like that, then I'd assume that OS X manages optimal settings itself.

Or is there something which I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no build-in power modes in Mac OS X. Still, the standard configuration in Mac OS X in combination with the high capacity batteries used in the MacBooks offers quite good battery life.

If you want to optimize your energy usage, you need to manually tweak settings.

Here's, what OS X offers to save power:

#### System Settings -> Energy Saver

- dim display when using battery
- display/computer sleep

#### System Settings -> Display

- Automatically adjust brightness

#### System Settings -> Security & Privacy

- disable remote control infrared receiver

#### Menubar

- Wifi Icon -> disable Wifi
- Bluetooth icon -> disable Bluetooth

Comment: Yes, looks like the settings you mentioned are pretty much all of what OS X offers to be configurable.